# How viral corneal ulcers due to HSV produce loss of sensation but painful at same time?

Tags: eye, ulcers, herpes-simplex, cornea

HSV= Herpes Simplex Virus

So, while reading about HSV keratitis I've come across a confusion,

> Dendritic ulcers of HSV produce extremely irritating ulcer (Parson 22ed pg180)

> dendritic ulcers of herpes are associated with marked diminution of corneal sensation (Khurana comprehensive opthalmology 7ed, pg111)

I even recall my proffessor teaching about hallmark feature of viral keratitis being loss of corneal sensation.

And my thinking is that Herpes being neurotropic virus should affect nerves,
however question is decreased or increased sensation because in herpes zoster opthalmicus or trigeminal neuralgia although caused by varicella but causes increased pain and both varicella and HSV belong to same family.

So did Parson go wrong here? or otherway round?